# How to get google analytics v3 API key

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am trying to fetch data from **Google Analytics API v3(analytics.data.ga.get)** for the first time. I have entered ids, start-date, end-date, metrics, dimensions in APIs Explore like below in screenshot:

[image]

One thing I don't know where I can find my API_KEY as I have to pass API_KEY in get request url.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A62299534&start-date=2015-01-01&end-date=2017-07-13&metrics=ga%3Ausers%2Cga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The API explorer is a little bit mistaken in that you actually need an `access_token` to make a request. You will first need to setup a [Developer project](https://console.developers.google.com/project), and setup OAuth 2.0 for your application.

Instructions can be found in the [quickstart guides](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js)

But for quicker way of getting an `access_token` that is valid for limited time you can use the [Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/) to formulate a request, and then click the button at the bottom of the report that says **Include current access_token in the Query URI (will expire in ~60 minutes).**

Comment: I have created credentials and getting `Client ID & Client secret` so which is used for API_KEY?

Comment: You need to follow the steps of exchanging the client ID & Client Secret for an `access_token` described in the [OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#basicsteps) docs. The `API_KEY` is more used for unauthenticated (no user data) APIs, like the [metadata api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/metadata/v3/) or [maps api](https://developers.google.com/maps/). The [OAuth playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) is a good place to get your feet wet at understanding the steps.